# How do you animate opacity in Cavalry?

Tags: animation, graphics

Most people mention that you must use the stagger behavior to animate opacity. How do you use the stagger function to have an object slowly fade into existence. The documentation doesn't say much but what the values mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the stagger function. Then animate the stagger function by going to certain frames and changing the maximum value to generate a keyframe. All the stagger function does is generate number values. So, hold the dot on the right side of the stagger function and drag it on to your object's opacity. This inputs the stagger function's value into the opacity value. Then it should work as intended.

The stagger function is a general value generator function, it's not just for opacity. Drag onto other values to animate them as well.